# Como puedo hacer que un prompt se repita y enseñe todos los caracteres introducidos concatenados?

Tags: javascript, bucles

Como puedo crear un programa que pida letras continuamente hasta que se pulse el botón cancelar?
El programa debe de mostrar todas las letras concatenadas al final.
Si introduzco un carácter que no sea una letra el programa lanzará un alert indicando que sólo se pueden introducir letras y continuará ejecutándose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```js
let rpta = ''
let arreglo = []

function comprobarLetra(letra) {
  return letra.length === 1 && letra.match(/[a-z]/i);
}

while (rpta != null) {
  rpta = prompt("escribe algo: ")

  if(rpta != null) {
    if (comprobarLetra(rpta)) {
    arreglo.push(rpta)
  } else {
    alert("solo introduce una letra!")
    }
  }
}

console.log(arreglo.join(''))
```